# assigning same html elements to a multiple variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am curious to know, how can i assign multiple html elements to a single variable in jquery...

for an example if i am having...

```
$('.some').drags();
$('.some1').drags();
```

at one instance i want variable `drgoff`

```
var drgoff = $('.some').offset().top;
```

at other instance i want variable `drgoff`

```
var drgoff = $('.some1').offset().top;
```

i am using this drgoff in the function, so now my question is how can i get all that html elements in place of `.some` when that particular html element is called...

`var drgoff` is not inside function it is a global variable..

thanx for any help...

it can be done using `if else` also but that will be too lengthy..

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `.add()`. `var drgoff = $('.some').add('.some1');`

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/ObiWaki/2/edit)

Comment: well sir i want `.some` to be replaced by `.some1` because i have many classes like that one...

Comment: thanx for your precious time...

Comment: @user3017928 it sounds like you're asking how to use a javascript function. You need to read some very basic javascript tutorials.

Comment: and `.add()` is not working for me..

Comment: if i use it inside a function offset will change every time i want it outside function...

Comment: @user3017928 it would be best if you post exactly what you're trying to do so that a better answer can be given. I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: check edit for the full code...

Comment: i am using drgoff for `top_margin` and `max_margin`

Comment: @user3017928 I won't be able to help you. That code is a mess. All I can say (again) is that if you want to do the same set of things but with a some value different, that's what functions are for. You would just pass a different selector to the function when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Well don't know when you are setting the value for `drgoff`. If you have a function (as indicated in question), then you can pass it the class name for which you want to get the value like this:

```
function getDragOffValue(cname){
    dragoff = $(cname).offset().top;
}
```

and use it like:

```
getDragOffValue(".name");
alert(dragoff);//gets value for elements with class .name

getDragOffValue(".name1");
alert(dragoff);//gets value for elements with class .name1
```

But I don't understand how your code will behave if you have multiple elements with same class name. It will return the `offset().top` value for first element in collection of elements with given class. In short `$(".name").offset().top` is as good as `$(".name:first").offset().top`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, well making an another function would be the best option..... but somehow i managed to do it inside drags() function.... thanks once again...